# Non-singular integral with parameter

Tags: calculus, integration

> For $t>0$, calculate integral $\int_0^\infty \sin(tx)e^\frac{-x^2}{4}\,dx$

I am having a problem with solving this type of task. I don't even know how to begin.

Comment: the answer is the Dawson-integral

Comment: see here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DawsonsIntegral.html

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$
\sin(tx)=\frac{\exp(\mathrm{i}tx)-
\exp(-\mathrm{i}tx)}{2\mathrm{i}}
$$

Comment: can you solve this problem by using derivation and continuity .

Comment: I do not see how you would do that.

Comment: I would reexpress the $\sin$ function in the integrand as I suggested and go from there.

Comment: It is necessary to do the task through the derivation of a subintegral function, while proving that the subintegral function is continuous and converges also for the derivation of the subintegral function, and then I calculate through the statement

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$ f(t) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(tx)e^{-x^2/4} \, dx $$

denote the integral in question. Then it follows that $f(0) = 0$ and

\begin{align*}
f'(t)
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} x \cos(tx)e^{-x^2/4} \, dx \\
&= \left[ -\frac{1}{2}\cos(tx)e^{-x^2/4} \right]_{0}^{\infty} - \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t}{2} \sin(tx)e^{-x^2/4} \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2} - \frac{t}{2}f(t).
\end{align*}

So we obtain an ODE with integrating factor $v(x) = \exp\left\{\int \frac{t}{2} \, dt \right\} = e^{t^2/4}$ and hence

$$ f(t) = \frac{1}{v(t)}\int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{2}v(u) \, du = \frac{1}{2} e^{-t^2/4} \int_{0}^{t} e^{u^2/4} \, du, $$

which can be written in terms of the [*Dawson integral*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DawsonsIntegral.html) as proposed in other comments.

Comment: In order to be able to use the statement I must first prove that the subintegral function is continuous and converges also for the derivation of a function.I do not know the Dawson integral and can that end be calculated differently?

Comment: @ceca, I am afraid I am not getting your comment. What is a subintegral function, which statement you are referring to and which properties do you think needs to be established? And it is proved that the integral $\int e^{u^2/4} \, du$ is not an elementary function. That's why people define new functions (like imaginary error function, Dawson integral, incomplete gamma function, to name a few) to express such integral.